# js timestamp to readable format... need to replicate php function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have come across a unique situation where I can no longer use php to format a timestamp and instead need to us jquery/js.

**in php :**

given ('2014-04-01 20:05:00', 'F jS, Y @ g:i a') would return 'April 1st, 2014 @ 8:05 pm'

```
// Date/time converter for strings
function convertStringTime($timestamp, $format)
{
    if ($timestamp == '' or $timestamp == 0)
    {
        return 'n/a';
    }
    else // return actual time
    {
        $timestamp = strtotime($timestamp);
        $timestamp = date($format, $timestamp);

        return $timestamp;
    }
}
```

I need to replicate this function in jquery/js with the same input and output.  I did some quick searching, but cannot find any sorts of built-in calls to format date/time.  Is there really nothing provided to do this?

Comment: http://www.datejs.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery dateFormat](https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat) is a separate plugin. You need to load that explicitly using a `<script>` tag. Directly you do not have any option.

Comment: nice find... this works great... thanks for the recommendation.